# How do you set an event to occur at a particular time?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a program that will initiate a few other functions at a certain second tonight, for new years, but I can't find any answers that work in Python 3. Does anyone have an answer to this? It happens to be 11:58:43 that needs to be executed on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **`datetime`** module in python to get the present date and time in any required format. Then you can easily implement what you are looking for provided , your python program keeps running checking for this time to be reached.

For this checking loop , it will check time for each second if you put a delay in your checking function as 1 second .

```
import time

time.sleep(1) # sleeps for 1 second.
```

I suggest a better method for your purpose .

**On windows :-**   Use the inbuilt task scheduler to run your python program.

**On Linux :-**  Take a look at 'cron' jobs to do any tasks at any specified time pattern . Its very easy to implement.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the help of our above friend Natesh bhat, (who will keep his correct answer) I made this script:

```
import time
time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
currenttime = str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
print(currenttime)
#Actual Start Time
timetogo = "23:58:43"

#Time for testing (uncomment)
#timetogo = "18:00:00"

while True:
    currenttime = str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    if currenttime == timetogo:
        your_function_here()
```

Feel free to use it for yourself.